# For test coverage ,inserted OpportunityLineItem but it it is not covering

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
 List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = getOpportunityLineItems(oppIds);
     Map<Id , List<OpportunityLineItem>> oppLineItemMap = new Map<Id , List<OpportunityLineItem>>(); 
     for(OpportunityLineItem item : lineItems){
        if(oppLineItemMap.get(item.OpportunityId) != null){
          oppLineItemMap.get(item.OpportunityId).add(item);
        }else{
          List<OpportunityLineItem> lines = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
          lines.add(item);
          oppLineItemMap.put(item.OpportunityId , lines);
        }
     }
```

My test class where i inserted OpportunityLineItem

```
Product2 pr1 = new Product2(Name='Unit Test Product PR1 Dummy');
        pr1.ProductID__c='12344';
        insert pr1;
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = pr1.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;
        OpportunityLineItem OpplineItem=new OpportunityLineItem();
        OpplineItem.OpportunityId=opp.id;
        OpplineItem.ClubSpeed_CheckId__c=122334;
        OpplineItem.Quantity=5;
        OpplineItem.TotalPrice=455;
        OpplineItem.PricebookEntryId=standardPrice.id;
        insert OpplineItem;
```

Comment: Please help me know where i am doing mistake

Comment: What is happening here: `getOpportunityLineItems`? and is this method covered by your test class? Secondly, can you plz share your code coverage screenshot, it will help us track the issue way more quickly.

Comment: It's hard to help you because you retrieve your opportunity line items from the function getOpportunityLineItems and we can't see it. It seems that your method doesn't return your opportunity line item inserted in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your method that creates your PBE and OLI. Here's an example that's taken from the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm?search_text=getStandardPricebook). It appears to me that your total price doesn't match what's in your PB as it should.

```
@isTest
public class PriceBookTest {
    // Utility method that can be called by Apex tests to create price book entries.
    static testmethod void addPricebookEntries() {
        // First, set up test price book entries.
        // Insert a test product.
        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
            Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;

        // Get standard price book ID.
        // This is available irrespective of the state of SeeAllData.
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        // 1. Insert a price book entry for the standard price book.
        // Standard price book entries require the standard price book ID we got earlier.
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;

        // Create a custom price book
        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
        insert customPB;

        // 2. Insert a price book entry with a custom price.
        PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);
        insert customPrice;

        // Next, perform some tests with your test price book entries.
    }
}
```